# LibGDX and the GoogleApiClient setup/integration (first time)

Tags: java, libgdx, google-api, google-play-services, google-api-client

I'm stuck trying to add Google Play and then release my app on the Play Store. I made it in LibGDX by implementing the Screen class and now all of a sudden the Google guides are trying to make me create layout.xml and add loads of new stuff into my app simply to get a silly "sign-in" button.

The Google documentation on this subject is almost impossible to follow with a LibGDX project, and there is not much help on the LibGDX community forum.

This cannot be that difficult, I have obviously missed something simple! I believe that I have the GoogleApiClient and my own interface set up OK, and I have an instance of GoogleApiClient inside all of my classes that need it now, without errors.

The error comes when I try to make the stupid layout and have this at the beginning of my app (IE. I tried to create a simple layout.xml that just has the Sign-In button only, once the player clicks sign-in the app would start by calling "initialize..." inside the LibGDX Android Launcher as usual.

Currently I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.megabro.flappyturd, PID: 3799
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.megabro.flappyturd/com.megabro.flappyturd.AndroidLauncher}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.onResume()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3400)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.onResume()' on a null object reference
                      at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.onResume(AndroidApplication.java:299)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6766)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3377)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3440) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2713) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I'm posting the whole code that is causing issue on Pastebin, will put link here:

http://pastebin.com/F6sqQPDc

Comment: You forgot to post the link?

Comment: what's your requirement to use GoogleApiClient ? Is it for Leaderboard and Achievements ?

Comment: Hi mate, yes I went to publish one of my games (first timer!) at Play Store, I have Dev Console Account etc. It says I must have at least 5 acheivements. I have based them all of score (except last one which is for consistent re-triers). So all i need is the Games.unlockachievement() method really. But I seem to be stuck on the "Sign-In" button which the goolge guide says I must include in order to publish my app

Comment: calm down, we are here to help you dear.

Comment: Is your game required Achievements/Leaderboard or you're creating due to Dev Console says, 5 achievements are needed.

Comment: I dont "need" it, but i did always intend to include a Leaderboard if it was possible. I also do like the Achievements idea (I just want to implement a couple of acheivements for example getting 100 score).

Comment: That said, if you can show me a way to publish without either then I might explore that for now to at least get it up and live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you are using Intellij or Android Studio.

If yes integrate BaseGameUtils in your project

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Play-Game-Services-in-LibGDX#intellij-and-android-studio-setup

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelperListener, ActionResolver {
    private GameHelper gameHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initialize(new TutorialLibgdxGameservices(this), false);
    if (gameHelper == null) {
      gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
      gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    }
    gameHelper.setup(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        gameHelper.onStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        gameHelper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
        gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
        return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
    }

    @Override
    public void loginGPGS() {
        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                }
            });
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score) {
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "CgkI6574wJUXEAIQBw", score);
    }

    @Override
    public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
      Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), achievementId);
    }

    @Override
    public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
      if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), "CgkI6574wJUXEAIQBw"), 100);
      }
      else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
      if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
      }
      else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    }
}
```

And keep ActionResolver in core module for interfacing.

```
public interface ActionResolver {
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS();
    public void loginGPGS();
    public void submitScoreGPGS(int score);
    public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId);
    public void getLeaderboardGPGS();
    public void getAchievementsGPGS();
}
```

Comment: hi again Abhishek. thanks for the speedy answer. I am using Android Studio and I have copied the BaseGameUtils folder into my project exactly as suggested by the google pages. I'm sure it is working as when I comment out my code on the layout/view (inside AndroidLauncher) it all works fine (ie. no gradle issuses etc). I am now going to read through your code and try to fit this into my project. Thanks very much for the kind help. I;ll come back ASAP and let you know if it worked in my app. (PS. I tried to vote-up your posts but due to being new here I couldn't). Back soon,trying this rightnow!

Comment: hi again friend. my first question is that is "ActionResolver"" interface the same as my GoogInterface in my code? and a) what methods should the ActionResolver have and b) what package should i make ActionResolver (ie. Android/Core/Desktop - in android studio)

Comment: ActionResolver is part of core that used for interfacing. It is same like your GoogInterface

Comment: this will be set as correct answer im sure but i just need to work a little more (hopefully only a little more :DD)

Comment: Abhishek thanks, so I will adapt my GoogInterface to perform with this code above (ie. act the same as ActionResolver). What methods from the above are a part of the ActionResolver interface? as when i implement GoogInterface I have to pull in  a load of methods I created which arent in your example)... Actually it was only one method different, in my GoogInterface I for some reason have method: onShowAchievementsRequested()  do I even need that there since it appears that isnt part of ActionResolver?

Comment: also the initialize (initialize(new TutorialLibgdxGameservices(this), false);) has 2nd parameter set to false in this example. But my Libgdx game class FlappyTurdGame doesnt have an override which fits this. its either one param only or the second is an 'AndroidApplicationConfiguration config'  -- so i have created one of those as member variable and called it config and passed it to that instantiation call to initialize (hope that made sense)

Comment: what is the working or implementation of your method onShowAchievementsRequested()

Comment: at the moment onShowAcheivementsRequested does absolutely nothing ... i just wanted to get the framework in place so that I could actually call my Games.acheivement.unlock() later once I know its working. Im in a right mess because I dont fully understand how to interfaces work and where to put them. I have a rough idea but when something doesnt work im in the dark

Comment: initialize(new MyGdxGame(this), cfg);

Comment: and catch **this** in your Game class of your core module and perform all action on that object

Comment: what's the status

Comment: OK GREAT NEWS! I used your code along with my GoogInterface interface (in place of ActionResolver)(which ive put inside my main core folder where the libgdx main game java class is). Now it all compiles lovely and all loads and I get a popup on the emulator asking me to sign in. So I am now back to where i was about 40 hours ago. I just need to figure out how to place the sign-in button now without using the layout.xml as described by google.

Comment: Thank you SOO MUCH for your help and assistance. I will keep working and come back here to report any progress. Hopefully you'll still be about as I am bound to run into more problems very soon :| (if you do have a solution of how best to put the "Sign-In" google button into my game I would be even more grateful.. Anyway Thanks again bro, you stopped my punching a hole in my pc case :)

Comment: sorry pal, im making another question as i dont understand what a couple of the methods here do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147557/google-api-client-interface-methods-explanation

Comment: THIS GUY'S A FLIPPIN' HERO . SOD THE BADGE HE DESERVES A MEDAL (espeically since it was 4am his country whilst he was taking the trouble to help me properly)!! +100 for you bro. (ps. i was so close to having the solution all along, just needed a helpful soul such as Abhishek here to walk me through it. What a guy!!

Comment: My first game of many has just been published. This is one of my simpler games but it is fun and free nevertheless: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.megabro.flappyturd