# Google Api Client interface methods explanation?

Tags: java, libgdx, google-play, google-play-services

```
    @Override
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.event_score)), 100);
    }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
    }
}

@Override
public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 101);
    }
    else if (!gameHelper.isConnecting()) {
        loginGPGS();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what these methods do? I have them as part of implementing a GoogleApi interface I made in the context of a tutorial. I especially don't understand the 100 / 101 parts, but the whole thing, in general, is quite confusing for me.

PS. I am making a game in LibGDX and this is my first time touching the Google Play API (or I think any API for that matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Method `getLeaderboardGPGS` show you Leaderboard above your Activity
if you are already Signed in otherwise it start signing process.

Above method definition is from Libgdx wiki but it should be

```
private final static int REQUEST_CODE_UNUSED = 9002;

startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboardId)), REQUEST_CODE_UNUSED);
```

REQUEST_CODE_UNUSED is an arbitrary integer for the request code
    getString(R.string.leaderboardId) is LEADERBOARD_ID

taken from Google wiki

Second Method `getAchievementsGPGS` is used to show a player's achievements, call `getAchievementsIntent()` to get an Intent to create the default achievements UI.

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

where REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS is an arbitrary integer used as the request code.

Comment: hi again brother. Do you mean it actually will show the leaderboard on top of my game screen?

Comment: ok i dont understand though does this mean that the leaderboard will be showing over top of my game? of course I really only wannt it to show a leaderboard after player dies. I am just trying to load the facility to show a leader board for me to chose when

Comment: ahhh  i see about the REQUEST CODE, i did have that i will change  mine too, shame i still dont quite understand how this is working though :| thanks again for your very helpful answers

Comment: don't worry, over means your game Activity Stacked and new Activity starts by Android OS and you press back your activity popped from stack and finish Leaderboard Activity

Comment: right i see! thanks. so basically i pass the functionality of this with the "this" in my initialize. That was the GoogInterface overrides are available in my code so all i do is call them when i want to update the score or acheivements? also how do i actually go about displaying a log in button? Or is that better left for a new question once I have another long crack at implementing it myself (just hope i dont break anything haha)

Comment: OMG I have about 6-7 more games that I think id like to publish soon also .... Im very afraid now :S

Comment: ya very simple. just send reference of Googlnterface into core module and through **this**, work on core module. Make different implementation according to module.

Comment: what is the commands/code-lines for calling in an actual Google Sign-In button without XML do you know? I already remember reading bits about this topic on Google guides but  now I cant find it

Comment: I need to check that. I'll check tomorrow. now i m going to sleep its 4 am

Comment: to be honest im still very confused my GoogInterface appears to be linked to nothing.... Oh WOW didnt realise it was late for you. totall apreciate your help thank you. Sorry to have caused you to have a late one . all the ver y best to you

Comment: what do you mean by linked to nothing ?

Comment: Ill tell you tomorrow mate. What I mean is that I have made Goog Interface but the methods dont seem to do anything. I belive it is just acting as a "middle-man" to access the Google methods such as unlockAcheivement but I just dont see how it actually works. You need to sleep tho bro thanks for your help I might be able to play around with it from here and figure it all out. ill let you know. Mate uve been excellent I wish i could repay the favour someday

Comment: I'm now stuck on checking whether the player is signed in before unlocking the achievement. I was using if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
//   // Call a Play Games services API method, for example:
//   Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.achievement_poop_slinger));
//  } else {
//   // Alternative implementation (or warn user that they must
//   // sign in to use this feature)
//  }   ---but now i no longer have any mGoogleApiClient instance

Comment: OK I think i solved it: if (game.googInterface.getSignedInGPGS()) {
   // Call a Play Games services API method, for example:
            game.googInterface.unlockAchievementGPGS("CgkI0_Wb3ukPEAIQAQ");
  } else {
   // Alternative implementation (or warn user that they must
   // sign in to use this feature)
  }

Comment: what i didnt (and still dont really) understand is how the method googInterface.getSignedInGPGS() even returns the correct value (ie. i believe false in this case) . very confusing but i think i have a functional publishable game now so on to next step with Google Dev console :)

Comment: OH NO :(( Massive disheartener... everything runs fine now but when I try to Build the Signed APK it fails saying mulitple dex define :( I had this issue a few days ago when I veery first tried what i had implemented. Here is the error: Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException