# Integrating Google API into libgdx project

Tags: android, google-api, libgdx

I have followed Aryan's suggestion from this question [LibGDX and the GoogleApiClient setup/integration (first time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145671/libgdx-and-the-googleapiclient-setup-integration-first-time) but can't seem to get it to work.

I created the ActionResolver and implemented it into my AndroidLauncher along with GameHelpListener, but the line 
    `gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);`
gives me an error, saying that GameHelper cannot be applied to this(AndroidLauncher)... I have been struggling with this for days now and can't seem to get anywhere.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is my AndroidLauncher code

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdHandler, GameHelper.GameHelperListener, ActionResolver {
```

// some code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

// more code

```
    if (gameHelper == null) {
        gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
        gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
    }
    gameHelper.setup(this);
```

// more code

```
}
```

My main class extends game, so I am assuming that this code needs to be in AndroidLauncher.  Am I wrong about this?

Thanks

Comment: Previously we're using `BaseGamUtils` module inside our project when auth is part of google game service.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I actually have BaseGameUtils in my project.  But I may not be using it correctly...  This whole Google API business has been giving me headaches for about a week.

Comment: try this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135531/signinsilently-failure-when-trying-to-sign-in-to-googleplay-game-services-w/48135617#48135617) , let me know if you're facing any issue again.

Comment: This looks very promising, but now I'm having issues with BaseGameUtils.  GameHelperUtils is full of errors.  I followed someones directions who was using Eclipse.  What do I need to do for Android Studio?

Comment: remove BaseGameUtils from your project, not required now, add auth and game service in `build.gradle` file sync and follow above given thread link

Comment: Please use Android Studio, Eclipse deprecated for Android very long time ago.

Comment: I think it works!  I finally got a message to sign in!  Now I have to customize the code but it seems to have done the job... Thank again man, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome, Happy coding..:)

Comment: Save yourself effort by using the Gameservices extension for libGDX to integrate Google Play Games. GitHub Repo is here: https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-gamesvcs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145671/libgdx-and-the-googleapiclient-setup-integration-first-time) in above question using older version of Google Play Services.

Previously we're using `BaseGameUtils` utility module for Leaderboard and Achievement. `(play service version <11.6.2)`

In latest version of `google play game service`, `BaseGameUtils` not required. Inject below dependency in your android module and follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135531/signinsilently-failure-when-trying-to-sign-in-to-googleplay-game-services-w/48135617#48135617).

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${gms_library_version}"
```

Comment: One more question... I would like to be able to call `startSignInIntent()` or `signOut()` from my main menu screen.  I tried using `app.actionResolver.startSignInIntent();` but it doesn't do anything.  The only way I can currently call startSignInIntent is through the ApplicationLauncher onCreate...  I also have an AdHandler in my code, so I tried including `signOut()` when an ad plays, but then I get the message that I can't access the method from a static context...

Comment: First sign out and then call then call starSigninintent, also check is there any issue in interfacing

Comment: You were right.  It was a mistake in my interfacing... It works now! Thanks again!

Comment: I've managed to get stuck again... I implemented achievements and they work, but I don't get a notification when an achievement is unlocked... `public void unlockAchievement(int achievementNum) {
  if(isSignedIn()) {
   if(achievementNum==1) {
    Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
      .unlock(getString(R.string.achievement_baby_steps));
   }}` When I check the achievements, they're unlocked but there is never a popup to tell me that it has been unlocked.  I'm assuming I need a piece of code to tell google to send a notification.

Comment: This seems to have taken care of it: https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=27559

Comment: Great, i'm glad to know that.

Comment: I have noticed an issue with the above implementation. Sometimes when I turn on airplane mode the game crashes whenever it tries to unlock/increment an achievement or open the leaderboard/achievements. I have also been able to replicate it by turning off WIFI and mobile data, then resetting the phone. It crashes with a NullPointerException that points to this line of code `mLeaderboardsClient.getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_tournament_leaders)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>()` inside `public void showLeaderBoard()`