# Stability issue with Google-API instantiation (My game sometimes crashes when there is no internet connection)

Tags: android, google-api, libgdx, instantiation, leaderboard

I am currently working on my second android game using libgdx.  Both of my games use similar Google API instantiation that handles the leaderboards and achievements.  I followed these steps to get the Google API to work ([Integrating Google API into libgdx project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855307/integrating-google-api-into-libgdx-project)).  The games run well for the most part.  I have recently noticed that both games sometimes crash when there is no internet connection, because they are trying to update achievements or leaderboards.  The problem is that it doesn't happen if I just play the game in airplane mode.  I have only been able to replicate the issue by taking out my sim card and disconnecting from WIFI and then restarting my phone.  Then the game crashes when it tries to reach my leaderboard and or achievements...  Crashlytics always gives me a NullPointerException when the game crashes.

I have tried adding an if statement `if(isSignedIn())` which calls `return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null;` to make sure that the player is signed in, but that does not seem to make a difference.

The easiest example of the crash would be updating my leaderboard.  In my Androidlauncher I call

```
public void submitScore(String type, int score){
        if(type.equals("tournament")){
            if(isSignedIn()) {mLeaderboardsClient.submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_tournament_leaders), score);}
        }
        if(type.equals("arcade")){
            if(isSignedIn()) {mLeaderboardsClient.submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_arcade_leaders), score);}
        }
    }
```

I don't call `mLeaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, googleSignInAccount);` until the game connects to Google.  Does this cause the crash?  I only have `private LeaderboardsClient mLeaderboardsClient;` up to that point...  I'm under the impression that `if(isSignedIn())` would prevent the game from trying to access mLeaderboardsClient.  Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: I don't know enough specifics to give an answer, but I suspect you need some `try`...`catch` blocks around your update code, and if an exception is thrown, remember what needs to be updated locally and retry later. The problem with network connectivity problems is they can happen anytime: you might successfully "sign in", but then the network goes down in the middle of updating a leaderboard.

Comment: So you think I should have a `try`...`catch` around any part of code that talks to Google?  Something like this? `try {app.actionResolver.unlockAchievement(14);}catch(NullPointerException n){System.out.println("not connected");} `

Comment: Check out gdx-gamesvcs lib on GitHub and see its code for Play Games. Or even better, just use this lib, that's what it is intended for.